# Remove particular segment from url

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I am using Codeigniter for one of my apps and have a following htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now i have a url which is like mydomain.com/group/username

For SEO reasons i am suppose to convert this url into mydomian.com/group/username into mydomian.com/username using 301 redirect

Also urls like mydomain.com/group/username/page1 should redirect to mydomian.com/username/page

The closest i have tried after googling is by pasting this below line at the end of the file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?group(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

But it isnt working.. any idea where i have gone wrong ?
The answers on other questions doesnt seem to be working for me/ Am pretty bad with .htaccess

**P.S -** i tried this

```
  RewriteRule ^group/username(.*)$ username/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

It works fine but it gives consecutive slashes like **mydomain.com/username//pagename**

Comment: Did you try custom routing without 301 redirect? [URI Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: yes, i did. but i have to achieve this using htaccess

Comment: You must not redirect all pages for seo. Bots see 301 redirects. But i'll look for htaccess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out

```
  RewriteRule ^group/username(.*)$ username$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

This is will simply remove the 'group' from your URL and will do 301 redirect

Answer (score 0):

If

```
RewriteRule ^group/username(.*)$ username/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

gives two slashes, change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^group/username/(.*)$ username/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

The (.*)$ matches anything after username (including the slash) until the end.